# Semantic Web :Tutorial on RDF dev

Tags: rdf, semantic-web

I am new to Semantic Web. I want to start working on creating some basic RDF document and publish them to get a feel how it works.I found a lot of information about the concepts,vocabulary etc but I couldn't find any thing related to development as what is the development environment required, what are the tool required. I am from .net background . Is there any tutorial available on how to get started and use rdf in web pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its real easy to be confused at first, but its ultimately simple enough. I liked this UMBC equity [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldl0m-5zLz4) on RDFa, its starts by explaining RDF, gives you a nice human readable notation for reference (N3) and then shows you how to put RDF into normal web pages using the RDFa attributes.

I've also started publishing [my own RDFa](http://feelitlive.com/events/2008/11/12/WC1E/7HY/ULU/Nizlopi) about music events and found the [RDFa distiller](http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/) handy for translating my RDFa into alternative syntaxes (there are lots) so that I can check my work.

If RDFa suits your use-case, then check out the RDFa.info wiki for [a review of common errors](http://rdfa.info/wiki/Common-publishing-mistakes). Even MySpace got some of these wrong.

It should be noted that RDFa is not the only way to publish RDF, but its the most awesome :-)

Answer (score 1):

The most known API for handling a set of semantic triples (subject,predicate, value) is called Jena: see http://jena.sourceforge.net/. There is a simple [tutorial](http://jena.sourceforge.net/tutorial/RDF_API/index.html) where you'll leran to manipulate a simple triple (RDF) store.

Start with this you'll then, later, learn RDFS/OWL (the ontology stuff)

Comment: I like Jena, but its more for storing and querying rather than publishing, though you can of course publish from it by storing something then querying it ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend reading an introduction about semantic web technologies such as [link text](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262012421).
Then, you could get down to examining semantic web tools out there. A comprehensive list of these tools could be found at [link text](http://esw.w3.org/topic/SemanticWebTools/).

Answer (score 0):

For an RDF API for .NET, see http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/